# Asp.Net ReportViewer Line Chart background

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I pass a dataset to my report, which renders a line chart showing a sprint burn down chart. One of the fiends in the dataset is 'PeriodType', which can be either 'Planning, 'Burning' or 'Retrospective'.

The chart shows dates along x axis, and the y axis holds hours.

What I would like to do, is grey the background, where the x axis has a value that is not a 'Burning' period. So the object that is used to create the chart, as mentioned, has a type field I can use.

Is there a way to change the background colour of the x 'columns' based on the flag? Some sort of conditional background colouring? I have searched, but can't seem to find such a handy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.
Open the Properties pane, in the `BackgroundColor` or `Color` (whichever is relevant) property of the chart, enter an IFF statement like:

```
=IIF(Str(Fields!PeriodType.Value) <> "Burning", "Gray", "SomeOtherColor")
```

Hope that helps